# Flutter WebView retain access token

Tags: flutter, webview, single-sign-on, token, flutterwebviewplugin

I am building a flutter application that will at some point within the app open a webview visiting
web-pages behind my SSO application.

As of right now when the user logs in using the [**flutter_AppAuth** plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_appauth) , the user is given a token that
is stored within the application.

When the user clicks a link to a secured site, the application opens the URL in a [web-view](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_webview_plugin) with the token placed within the header and is verified as a user that is logged in. My problem is once on this page, clicking another link on the web-page forces me to the sso login page even though the token had been accepted previously.

My question is how do I ensure that the token is stored and is used as the user navigates the web-page to ensure they don't have to login again?